# How to find and replace only first two hyphens in sql ex 'UTR-ATLAS-006-0143391-002'

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to find and replace only first two hyphens with a pipe `|` in SQL Server.

For example:
'UTR-ATLAS-006-0143391-002' becomes 'UTR|ATLAS|006-0143391-002'

Comment: This is missing a *lot* of detail - replace.. with what? Examples needed, what have you tried? Show your attempt so far. And *tag* your database, string functions are highly vendor-specific.

Comment: Replace it with pipe | . I tried select REPLACE('UTR-ATLAS-006-0143391-002','-','|') but this is replacing all hyphones in the string

Answer (score 0):

In an RDBMS that has the regexp functions this would be simple.

F.e. in Postgresql, by using a regex with 2 capture groups and lazy search

```
regexp_replace(str,'^(.*?)-(.*?)-','\1|\2|')
```

In Sql Server, without regex functions, it's a bit harder.

**Using charindex or patindex to locate the positions of the dashes**

```
select str
, new_str = case when patindex('%-%-%', str) > 0
            then stuff( stuff(str, charindex('-',str),1,'|')
                       ,charindex('-',str,charindex('-', str)+1)
                       ,1,'|')
            else str end
from (values
  ('UTR-ATLAS-006-0143391-002')
, ('NO DASHES IN THIS STRING')
) test(str)
```

```
select str
, new_str = replace(left(str, charindex('-', str, charindex('-', str)+1)), '-', '|') 
                    + right(str, len(str) - charindex('-', str, charindex('-', str)+1)) 
from (values
  ('UTR-ATLAS-006-0143391-002')
, ('NO DASHES IN THIS STRING')
) test(str)
```

**Deconstruction & reconstruction of the string**

```
select str
, new_str = (select stuff(string_agg(iif(rn<=2+1,'|','-')+value,''),1,1,'') 
             from (select value, row_number() over (order by (select null)) rn from string_split(str, '-')) q )
from (values
  ('UTR-ATLAS-006-0143391-002')
, ('NO DASHES IN THIS STRING')
) test(str)
```

**Returns:**

| str | new_str |
| --- | --- |
| UTR-ATLAS-006-0143391-002 | UTR|ATLAS|006-0143391-002 |
| NO DASHES IN THIS STRING | NO DASHES IN THIS STRING |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3e9fce36fa683e33182223d732eea3f4)*

Comment: Nice try - but `(order by (select null))` is logical nonsense and string_split does not guarantee order.

Comment: @SMor In theory I agree. But I have yet to see proof that string_split screws up the order for very few values. But, I'd much rather like it that MS would also bring the ordinal flag in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

```
Declare @testTable Table (TestString varchar(100));
 Insert into @testTable (TestString)
 Values ('UTR-ATLAS-006-0143391-002')
      , ('UTR-ATLAS-006-0143392-002')
      , ('UTR ATLAS 007 0143392 003');

 Select tt.TestString
      , updated_column = coalesce(stuff(stuff(tt.TestString, p2.pos, 1, '|'), p1.pos, 1, '|'), tt.TestString)
   From @testTable                                                      tt
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex('-', tt.TestString, 1)))               p1(pos)
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex('-', tt.TestString, p1.pos + 1)))      p2(pos)
```

Answer (score -1):

if this were DB2, you could use this:

```
with data (str) as (values
('UTR-ATLAS-006-0143391-002')
)
select regexp_replace(
           regexp_replace(str,'-','|', 1, 1),
           '-','|', 1, 1
       )
from   data
```

This would first replace the 1st occurrence of '-' and of the result again the first occurrence, which is actually the second in the string, giving:

```
UTR|ATLAS|006-0143391-002
```

Comment: Thanks. regex_replace doesn't work in SQL Server

Comment: *"if this were DB2"* but it's not.